# Rails Active Storage and existing cloud Storage objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

Trying to figure out a way to attach existing Cloud Storage objects to a `has_one_attached` or a `has_many_attached` attribute on the Rails side.

For example, if I was to run a Cloud Function and have it put the resulting files directly back into Cloud Storage, I would need the Cloud function to then pass a JSON array back to the app to give Active Storage the object keys

Reading the Rails API docs, one method shown was:

```
person.avatar.attach(params[:signed_blob_id])
```

So, once the function uploads it to the bucket, it should obtain the object's `blob_id`, and pass that back to the Rails app to attach it to the model?